# Active skills maximum at a shadowrunner's creation

Tags: character-creation, skills, shadowrun-sr5

The Life Module section of Run Faster p.66 limits active skill maximum to seven:

> Note that no active skill may be raised above 7 in this system.

What's the maximum for the other methods (Core Rulebook, Point Buy)?

Comment: You could just read the book. Is there a reason you are asking here?

Comment: Ok after your comment and the answer I found it p.88. It's not as easy to find back as the limit for attributes are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum skill rank when creating a character is **6** for both action and language/knowledge skills.

You can go up to 7 with the advantage "Talented".